# SecurityAccessDenied Exception, WCF Trace , Reemote debugging

Tags: wcf, iis-express

I did a lot of research on this topic and would like someone to point me in the correct direction. 
This is a common issue and I can't see to get it working. We have a webservice which uses IIS Express
http://localhost:1234/ProjectServices/MyService.svc

We have another windows application and trying to connect to the above service.

Whenever I try to invoke it ,

```
ButtonClick()
{

     return new WcfServiceProxy<IMyService>().Use(s => s.Save(typeid));

}
```

Whenever it reaches this point it gives me SecurityAccessDenied Access is denied exception

So I enabled WCF tracing on the service and client which tells me that there is a Fault Exception System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Access is denied.
and a lot more lines in it.. What is it that I would look for..?

I didn't know if the service was terminating the connect and tried to put a breakpoint. So added complilation="true" in the webconfig and appconfig. 
The screenshot explains the error.

Since we are using IIS express I used this link to help me
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/805238/Access-IIS-Express-Website-From-Remote-Machine. Didn't seem to help

Can someone point me in the correct direction.

[image]

Comment: does your service working properly in the server? try to view in your browser first.

Comment: @JrTabuloc: Yes it does work properly.. I can browse to it. I donno what it means by server. We use IISExpress

Comment: What does Save function do? Do you have security implementation with your service? Can you add more details?

Comment: Thank you @JrTabuloc : that was the problem.. There was security implemented and it didn't like the session. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: Can you add/post your client and service configuration?